# Phonetic fonts in website

Tags: html, character-encoding

I was trying to show some text in the website which contains phonetic symbols.

The text is being shown as:

```
yat karos£i yad aÅ›nÄsi
```

instead of my actual text:

```
yat karoṣi yad aśnāsi.
```

What could be the reason for the same? I have set my font to Lucida Sans Unicode.

Comment: Do you have `<meta charset="UTF-8"></meta>` tags in your HTML?

Comment: What character encoding are you using in your text editor to save the HTML file, and what character encoding does your web page declare that it uses?

Comment: @chipChocolate.py: Yes, I have those tags in my HTML code.

Comment: But are you using UTF-8 as the encoding in your text editor? If not, you'll be encoding the content one way, but telling the browser to decode it another way. Which leads to garbled characters.

Comment: @Arkanon and chipChocolate.py There was an issue with the character encoding only. I was not saving that as utf-8. It got resolved. Thanks

Comment: That's usually the cause, yes. I've posted an answer with an expanded explanation of the problem and solution.

Comment: The question does not describe what phonetic symbols were used (only incorrect rendering is shown). And it does not have a self-contained HTML document demonstrating the issue, or any code whatsoever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you see a non-Latin character replaced with one or more unusual characters, it usually means that the declared character encoding does not match the actual character encoding used to save the file.

If your web page declares (either through a `meta` element, or by way of HTTP headers) that it uses, for instance, UTF-8 encoding, then you need to make sure that the text editor you use to edit your HTML page is configured to save the file using that same character encoding.

Otherwise you save the file with one encoding, and then the visitor's web browser will try to decode the file with the declared (different) encoding, which means that some of the characters (especially the non-Latin ones) will become garbled the way you have seen in your example.